# Powershell specific character not match for function

Tags: regex, powershell, if-statement, scripting

Am trying to create a filter to only run the `IF` clause in case of the character in the 4 position be either `"W", "X", "Y", "Z"`.

The code so far looks like this:

```
$name= "123Y567"

if ($name.notcontains("Y"))
{
 "Action 1"
}
  else
{               
  "Action 2"
 }
}
```

I have tried this as well

```
$name= "123Y567"

if ($name -notmatch (/^.{4}["Y"]/))
{
 "Action 1"
}
  else
{               
  "Action 2"
 }
}
```

What could be the best solution for this? but new working with scripting and Powershell in general.

Comment: `if ($name -cmatch '^.{3}[W-Z]')` ?

Comment: a string can be treated as a character array. you can do `'asdfgh'[3]` to get `f` - which is the 4th letter since arrays start with zero. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without regex, as [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) already suggested, use `switch` on the 4th character:

```
$name= "123Y567"
switch ($name[3]) {
    'W' { Action_1 }
    'X' { Action_2 }
    'Y' { Action_3 }
    'Z' { Action_4 }
}
```

Or if the action to perform is the same for any of the characters 'W','X','Y','Z' :

```
$name= "123Y567"
if ('W','X','Y','Z' -contains $name[3] ) { Action_1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regex to check if the fourth char is a char in a custom range/set you may use

```
if ($name -cmatch '^.{3}[W-Z]')
```

Note that PS regex matching is case insensitive with `-match`, you need to use `-cmatch` to make it case sensitive.

The pattern matches

- `^` -  start of string
- `.{3}` - any 3 chars other than a newline
- `[W-Z]` - a `W`, `X`, `Y` or `Z`.